# Open-source HelpDesk solution for Windows?

Tags: active-directory, open-source, helpdesk, knowledge-base, cas

I'm looking for an open-source HelpDesk solution with the following features:

- CAS or direct AD integration
- Different priorities for different tickets
- KB generation (from tickets and manually)
- Email support (create, reply via email)
- Client can view progress via email or through web interface
- Hide comments from client
- Web form with custom options from drop-down

Unfortunately I only have a Windows Server to work with, so I can't use RT4.

Comment: About to install OTRS. Hopefully this will fit my needs.

Comment: OTRS is powerful and feature-rich, but also quite complex and has been written with Linux in mind as well - it is Perl of course and thus the code is portable, there is also "otrs4win32" including an installer, but I'd imagine you would hit limitations since Linux-specific dependencies would simply not be there.

Comment: The install went fine, I'll have to confirm it meets my requirements, but as far as I can tell, there are no features lost in interoperability.

Comment: If OTRS meets your needs please remember to come back and post a note (and a feature summary if it's missing anything/has anything extra from your needs) as an answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Running Windows does not preclude using RT - Perl (and all the required modules) can be obtained for Windows. I'm not saying this is a good solution, but it's an option - and it gives you all of the functionality you get with RT.

Another (better) option for using RT on Windows is [WinRT](http://www2.netvigilance.com/winrt), but note that it's several versions behind (3.4) and doesn't have the KB generation bits integrated as far as I know.

Comment: I wrote on the RT mailing-list, they said it wasn't possible and to look toward virtual-machines. RT 3.* is missing too many features to be useful :\.

Comment: RT on Windows is definitely not a supported setup, but I have seen it done.  Virtual Machines are another great option, though if OTRS meets your needs and runs on your primary platform it's probably a better choice - Less complexity is almost always better...